# Function app in Visual Studio 2019 16.10.0: no functions runtime

Tags: visual-studio, azure-functions

Yesterday I updated Visual Studio to the latest (Professional 2019 16.10.0)
But today suddenly my functionapp project isn't running anymore. A pup-up is shown with the exception: 'There is no Functions runtime available that matches the version specified in the project'. I'me still able to run my functionapp from command line, so I think the issue is with the new Visual Studio version.

I've got TargetFramework netcoreapp 3.1 and AzureFunctionsVersion V3.
Package Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid 3.2.0 and Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs 3.0.22,
Microsoft.Net.Sdk.Functions 3.0.9

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked out [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions#updating-2x-apps-to-3x-in-visual-studio)? You seem to have the correct values in your project file, but I wonder if you need to fetch the latest templates.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I followed the recommended steps for adding a functionapp project on your suggestion. And the newly added project ran as expected, even in the same solution, but unfortunately my first functionapp project kept the same message 'no functions runtime available corresponding to the version specified in the project'.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, so my colleague has found the solution. It turned out to be case sensitivity. When I changed the AzureFunctionsVersion from V3 to v3, the problem was solved!

Comment: Wow thanks for that, my project suddenly stopped working after upgrading VS.